# Random event with in unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, random

FYI I'm quite new with prograaming and c#. Sorry if this seem idioticly simple question.

I have a bit of difficulty to explain what I want to do. So basically, there is array/list of numbers. The number would be picked by using Random.Range(). Each number would have their own action they would active. For example, number 1 would boot up scene1, number 2 would boot up scene2 and so on. How do you assign this randomly chosen number to a certain action?

I don't even know how to put this in code (use array/string?), but the basic idea would probably look something like this:

```
int randomNumber = Random.Range(1, 10);

randomNumber[1] = SceneManager.LoadScene(Level1);

randomNumber[2] = SceneManager.LoadScene(Level2);
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71765650/7111561) is not exact ;)

The upper limit of [`Random.Range(int,int)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) is **exclusive** so

```
Random.Range(0, 10)
```

will never return `10` but values between `0` and `9`.

---

Even simplier actually would be to store all the scenes in an array e.g.

```
public List<string> scenes = new List<string>();
```

and then use

```
var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, scene.Length);
SceneManager.LoadScene(scenes[randomIndex]);
```

there is no need for a long and undynamic `if-else` or `switch-case`. The array/list can be fully dynamically adjusted in the Inspector or even on runtime without having to add more cases.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of going about this is:

```
int randomNumber = Random.Range(1, 10);
    
    if(randomNumber == 1) {
        // Load Scene 1
    } else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        // Load Scene 2
    }
```

**EDIT:**

You don't assign the random number in this case. You check if the random number is a specific number. You can check if numbers are equal using `==`.

The random number has a value between 1 and 9 and this number is random everytime you run the program.

If you want to do it more dynamically you can look at the answer from @derHugo. Depends on how you use it and how many if-else statements you have to write.